# How do I copy the value of a single element from a JavaScript array into another array at the same position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, clone

If I want to clone an array, I can use the slice() function, but what if I want to "clone" a single element? I want to do something like this:

```
array1[i] = array2[i];
```

but I want to copy the value, not the reference.
How can I do this? Also, will the solution work for associative arrays too? For example:

```
array1["one"] = array2["one"];
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: javascript doesn't have associative arrays, they are object literals and have no order. If using jQuery look at `$.extend()`

Comment: "If I want to clone an array, I can use the slice() function" No you can not.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
   var cloneItem = Object.assign({}, array1[i]);
   array2.splice(i, 0, cloneItem);
```

**EDIT**
The previous adds a clone item in the position, pushing the rest of the elements to the right. If you simply want to replace just do

```
array2[i] = Object.assign({}, array1[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
array1[i] = Object.assign({}, array2[i]);
```

But it doesn't work if there are primitives an array.
Also you can use slice method like you wrote:

```
array1[i] = array2.slice(i, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloning an array properly (without leaving any references in the nested structure) is not that simple. You need a tool for that. Unfortunately it is not a part of standard array methods. You have to develop it yourself. Such as

```
Array.prototype.clone = function(){
  return this.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? e.clone() : e);
};
```

Once you have this tool at hand you can clone the array first and then assign whatever item of the clone array you wish; such as `array1[i] = array2.clone()[i];`